# Modify an argument of a function that is inside another function, without having to redefine the whole function again

Tags: r, function

**Edit:**

The `labelFormat` function is from the `leaflet` package.
I would like to modify an argument inside the `format` function that is inside the `formatNum` function.

So from this:

```
labelFormat <- function (prefix = "", suffix = "", between = " &ndash; ", digits = 3, 
    big.mark = ",", transform = identity) 
{
    formatNum <- function(x) {
        format(round(transform(x), digits), trim = TRUE, scientific = FALSE, 
            big.mark = big.mark)
    }
    function(type, ...) {
        switch(type, numeric = (function(cuts) {
            paste0(prefix, formatNum(cuts), suffix)
        })(...), bin = (function(cuts) {
            n <- length(cuts)
            paste0(prefix, formatNum(cuts[-n]), between, formatNum(cuts[-1]), 
                suffix)
        })(...), quantile = (function(cuts, p) {
            n <- length(cuts)
            p <- paste0(round(p * 100), "%")
            cuts <- paste0(formatNum(cuts[-n]), between, formatNum(cuts[-1]))
            paste0("<span title=\"", cuts, "\">", prefix, p[-n], 
                between, p[-1], suffix, "</span>")
        })(...), factor = (function(cuts) {
            paste0(prefix, as.character(transform(cuts)), suffix)
        })(...))
    }
}
```

I would like to have this:

```
labelFormat <- function (prefix = "", suffix = "", between = " &ndash; ", digits = 3, 
    big.mark = ",", transform = identity) 
{
    formatNum <- function(x) {
        format(round(transform(x), digits), trim = TRUE, scientific = FALSE, 
            big.mark = big.mark, decimal.mark = ',')
    }
    function(type, ...) {
        switch(type, numeric = (function(cuts) {
            paste0(prefix, formatNum(cuts), suffix)
        })(...), bin = (function(cuts) {
            n <- length(cuts)
            paste0(prefix, formatNum(cuts[-n]), between, formatNum(cuts[-1]), 
                suffix)
        })(...), quantile = (function(cuts, p) {
            n <- length(cuts)
            p <- paste0(round(p * 100), "%")
            cuts <- paste0(formatNum(cuts[-n]), between, formatNum(cuts[-1]))
            paste0("<span title=\"", cuts, "\">", prefix, p[-n], 
                between, p[-1], suffix, "</span>")
        })(...), factor = (function(cuts) {
            paste0(prefix, as.character(transform(cuts)), suffix)
        })(...))
    }
}
```

See the new argument `decimal.mark` inside the `format` function.
But to do this, I would not like to **redefine** the `labelFormat` function.

In Python there's something that I use quite similar to modify an argument inside a function. Let's suppose that we want to modify the default behaviour of `json.dumps`:

```
import functools
import json

my_json_dumps = functools.partial(json.dumps, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Now I can call `my_json_dumps` instead of using `json.dumps`, this way I don't needed to define the whole function again.

My problem is a little different, because I need to modify an argument that is inside an inner function!

Comment: The variables inside a function won't be available in you global environment. It's best to not define a function inside another. Just create it before the other one and use it inside the second.

Comment: The function `g` is only created when `f` is run. (And is re-created every time `f` is run with a different environment, so you get a "different" `f` each time.) If the value returned from `f` does not enclose the value of `g`, it will not exist after the function `f` is called. Given that what you are asking for doesn't make a lot of sense, can you describe more the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you were able to modify it, you could assign the `g()` function to a global variable by using the `<<-` assignment.

Comment: It would definitely be useful if you gave a little more context - i.e. is this a practical question, or an "I was just wondering how ...?" question?

Comment: I added more context, and I think is better to rename the answer's title now...thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I decided to change the title because of the comments above

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example with sample input data that we can run to test the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case `labelFormat` returns a function that contains a reference to the environment where `formatNum` is defined. Here we can create a wrapper to change that value

```
my_labelFormat <- function(...) {
   fun <- labelFormat(...)
   evalq(formatNum <- function(x) {
     format(round(transform(x), digits), trim = TRUE, scientific = FALSE, 
            big.mark = big.mark, decimal.mark = ',')
  }, environment(fun))
  return(fun)
}
```

So we call the default `labelFormat` function but them manipulate the environment to change the `formatNum` function

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy.  There's no way I know of to call `g()` from outside of `f()`, since that function *does not exist* until after you call `f()` and execute the first step. To see this, try the following:

```
debug(f)
f(1)
ls() ## shows 'number', the only object in the local environment
g()  ## Error: could not find function g
<ENTER>
<ENTER>
g()  ## prints 'Hi', because the function has now been defined
```

A super-cheesy way to get at the definition of `g()` would be:

```
eval(body(f)[[2]])
g()
## "Hi"
```

This picks the second element out of the expression that defines the function, which happens to be the definition of `g()`, and evaluates it in the current environment.